# Как отключить масштабирование объекта в three.js

Tags: javascript, html, 3d, three.js

Пишу код для игральной кости. При изменении ширины экрана и перезагрузке страницы куб становится непропорциональным, т.е как-то сам масштабируется. Можно это как-то отключить?
Код создания куба:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: document.getElementById('canvas') });
renderer.setSize(400, 400);

var material = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture/dice_1.png') }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture/dice_6.png') }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture/dice_3.png') }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture/dice_4.png') }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture/dice_5.png') }),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture/dice_2.png') })
];
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(3.5, 3.5, 3.5), material);

scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;
```

Comment: Если размер рендерера постоянный (400 х 400), то аспект камеры при ее инициализации должен быть не `window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight`, а `400 / 400`, или проще `1`. И тогда обработчик события `resize` для окна - не нужен. Кроме того, зачем плодить дубли вопросов? Создан же уже один тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1512783/224917, его и правь, или удали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: 
document.getElementById('canvas') });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

var material = [
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture/dice_1.png') }),
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture/dice_6.png') }),
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture/dice_3.png') }),
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture/dice_4.png') }),
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture/dice_5.png') }),
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/texture/dice_2.png') })
];
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(3.5, 3.5, 3.5), material);

scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 5;

function onWindowResize() {
camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
```